# how to create a new array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I don't understand the way this is working. Im tring to create an array of strings from a list of strings.  I count the number of strings in the list and then want to create an array of these strings.  I was doing some testing and came up with  this code:

```
string *newOrder;

int numNodes;

numNodes = alphaTree.numNodes();

newOrder = new string [numNodes];

newOrder[0] = "This is";
newOrder[1] = "a test";
newOrder[2] = "To see";
newOrder[3] = "If this";
newOrder[4] = "will work";
```

The results are that newOrder acts like it is a single string array having the vaule "This is".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use `std::vector`. All use of `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, `delete[]`, `~T()`, `malloc`, or `free` should be avoided except in a class that does nothing else but call them (for example, when writing a custom smart pointer or typesafe union).

Comment: Too new to programing.  I don't know what a smart pointer or typesafe union is, but I'd like to know your reasoning for not using the code you listed above.

Comment: The point is only advanced things such as smart pointers and typesafe unions should call those things directly. Using a vector prevents leak of memory and can protect against buffer overruns.

Comment: Voting to close as the code is correct but the problem was misunderstanding of the debugger view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if numNodes = alphaTree.numNodes(); is returning desired size.

The following is a correct piece of code, allocates for 5 strings, and assigns.

```
newOrder = new string [5];
newOrder[0] = "This is";
newOrder[1] = "a test";
newOrder[2] = "To see";
newOrder[3] = "If this";
newOrder[4] = "will work";
```

If you execute the following statement:

```
cout << newOrder[2] << endl;
```

This will print: To see

Comment: it returns 5.  Using the debugger in VS I can see the end result after all the strings have been assigned and all it shows is "This is". It has index numbers next to each letter when I expand it in the locals window.

Comment: Ahh yes.  I guess since newOrder is a pointer it will only show the first element in the array that is pointing to.  Thanks!  Alow my self... to confuse...my self....

Comment: @user3600424 If the problem is the debugger, then reword your question that it is a debugger display issue, not a programming issue.  Right now, your question sounds like a programming issue.

Comment: Perhaps my comments were worded poorly.  This was a programming issue.

Comment: @user3600424 So how is the answer you accepted different than the code you posted in your question?  I see no difference, except that we don't see a couple of variable declarations, and that `numNodes` is used instead of `5`.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part.  I had not realized that since newOrder was a pointer that when using the debugger to see the values in newOrder, it would only show me the value of the first element.  I then thought that there was only one value being held on newOrder.  The code was correct and I realized this after displaying each element of newOrder.

Answer (score 0):

```
using std::string;
using std::vector;

// from an initializer_list
vector<string> newOrder1 = {
    "This is",
    "a test",
    "To see",
    "If this",
    "will work",
};

// as a sequence of appends
// often used in a loop if an iterator is not applicable
vector<string> newOrder2;
newOrder2.push_back("This is");
newOrder2.push_back("a test");
newOrder2.push_back("To see");
newOrder2.push_back("If this");
newOrder2.push_back("will work");

// from an iterator-pair over any standards-compliant container
vector<string> newOrder3(alphaTree.begin(), alphaTree.end());
```